# c# moq test async task

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I am trying to use Moq for test some Async Task stuff with no sucess.

I could make the the mock stuff, but when I try to use mock.Object it throws (Object = 'm.Object' threw an exception of type 'Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.GeneratorException') and VS stops to debug/run.

Here id the Moq way of the test:

```
interface ITestAsync
        {
            Task<IEnumerable<string>> get();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task MoqShouldReturnFIRST()
        {
            var m = new Mock<ITestAsync>();
            m.Setup(q => q.get()).ReturnsAsync(null);

            var x = await m.Object.get().FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync();

            x.Should().BeNull();
        }
```

Here is the test in the traditional way using xUnit

```
public class FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsyncTests
    {

        private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> getAll()
        {
            List<string> x = new List<string>();
            x.Add("01");
            x.Add("02");

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return x;
        }

        private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> getNull()
        {
            List<string> x = new List<string>();
            x = null;

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return x;
        }

        private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> getEmpty()
        {
            List<string> x = new List<string>();

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return x;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldReturnFIRST()
        {
            var x = await getAll().FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync();

            x.Should().Be("01");
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldReturnNULLforNULL()
        {
            var x = await getNull().FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync();

            x.Should().BeNull();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldReturnNULLforEMPTY()
        {
            var x = await getEmpty().FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync();

            x.Should().BeNull();
        }
    }
```

My Extention that I am trying to test is:

```
public static async Task<T> FirstIfNotNullOrEmptyAsync<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> obj) where T : class
        {
            var result = await obj;

            return (result != null && result.Any()) ? result?.FirstOrDefault() : null;
        }
```

Comment: Recreated tests from the example all all tests pass. Only initial issue was that the interface was private (but guessing that was due to minimal example) . Once interface was made public everything worked/passed

Comment: Include the entire exception message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only initial issue was that the interface was private (but guessed that was due to minimal example).

Got the following error

> Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.GeneratorException: Can not create
>   proxy for type
>   Moq.IMocked`1[[****+ITestAsync,
>   *****, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   because type ****+ITestAsync is not
>   accessible. Make it public, or internal and mark your assembly with
>   [assembly:
>   InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]
>   attribute, because assembly Moq is strong-named.

Once interface was made public everything worked/passed

```
public interface ITestAsync {
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> get();
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect! worked! another question. Running the code coverage, even these tests testing all possibilities of the extention, it says that is only 90% covered because is missing the test of MoveNext() part. How can I test this if all are already tested? what is missing? cheers.

Comment: That is outside of my current knowledge base of that topic. Ask the community after searching and see if they can help. Happy coding!!!!